# og:image does not work [Facebook Open Graph]

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

The image does not appear when I share the url.
I have used the Object Debugger but the problem continues.

[image]

Below is my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Continental 1120 - Player">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Continental 1120">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://continental1120.esy.es/imgs/logo.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="117">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="60">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the warning output tells that you should add the meta og:url.
By the way if i try to share the link http://continental1120.esy.es/popup.php, the image is correctly shared.